# CSS - list of links to read. a:visited::before doesn't do what I expect

Tags: html, css

basically this:  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KaLarE

I'd like to create a list of links, with a checkbox before each.  Then check the boxes if the link has been visited.

I tried this, but only got no's, which stinks.  [smirk]

```
a::before {
  content: 'no'
}
a:visited::before {
  content: 'yes'
}
```

If I could do it w/o JS, that would be amazing :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can in CSS. HTML is escaped automatically, so you cannot set a checkbox there (modify the `content` example of no's with `<p>NOOOOOO</p>` to see what I say).

The only way would be with JS: iterate over all groups of input-a, then for each `input` check if its sibling `a` is visited (`:visited`). In jQuery would be like `$(this).prop("checked", $(this).siblings("a").eq(0).is(":visited"));`.

Sorry for not posting code, have no time. But that should be the codeto give inside the for loop. Will type later when I get back.

Comment: That's JQ...just saying.

Comment: Yeah, so I pointed out that he cannot do it in CSS, and the only way is JS. And he just said "could", so no more options are available except someone with more knowledge can provide more answers.

Comment: I was planning to use the HTML character in content, but it looks like that doesn't work.  e.g. &#9744;  This works ok - I didn't want to have to track what was visited and what wasn't.  This JQ has the browser do that, so FTW!